# pointer producing more results than available in an array

Tags: c, pointers

```
include<stdio.h>

void function(int*);

int main(){
    int num[]={-3,8,12,90};

    function(num);
}

void function(int* array){
    for(;*array!='\0';array++)
      printf("\n%d",*array);
}
```

pointer should print elements of the array, however it keep on producing four more results.

Comment: what makes you think there is a 0 in that array? That's how strings work, not arbitrary arrays

Comment: That is an int array, not a char array specifically containing a null terminated string. You didn't put an element in it containing a '\0'. And by the way, it is possible to have char arrays without a null terminator as well, they just don't qualify as c style strings.

Comment: Even if you did put a `0` at the end of the array, you would compare the element to `0`, not the null character `'\0'`, which is what you would use if it were a string.

Comment: @TomKarzes `0` and `'\0'` are the same integer value. It will automatically convert the types to match.

Comment: Add the 0 sentinel: `int num[]={-3,8,12,90};` --> `int num[]={-3,8,12,90,0};`?

Comment: @Barmar It''s misleading.  `'\0'` implicitly indicates that you're dealing with a character value.  In this context, it's equivalent to an incorrect comment.  Also, no type conversion is needed:  `'\0'` has type `int`, not `char`, just as all character literals do.

Comment: @TomKarzes While I agree that it's better style to use `'\0'` only when comparing with characters, it's not very wrong to mix the types here.

Comment: @Barmar If I were grading it as an assignment, I'd take off a point or two for that.  It's poor style to use `'\0'` when not dealing with characters, or to use `0` when dealing with characters.

Comment: i mistakenly thought it contain null terminated character...thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

This is a null-terminated char array, aka c-string:

```
const char *cstr = "Hello";

//which is same as

const char carr[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

If you have for example an array of `int`, like in your example:

```
int num[] = {-3,8,12,90};
```

and if you want to pass that array to a function, then in addition you have  to specify a length specifier, like:

```
void function(int* array, unsigned int len) {/*...*/} //better size_t as type
                                                      //for len (stddef.h)
```

call like:

```
function(num, sizeof num / sizeof num[0]);
```

Maybe it's worth to mention, that:

```
//'pointer to int != array of int'
int* != int[]
```

although, passing an array as function argument, that array decays to a pointer (see [Array to pointer conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Array_to_pointer_conversion)).